# php mysql select dropdown multiple related tables

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment i have 2 tables and can only use PHP (no javascript).

```
table category:

id, name
1, mymother
2, hismother
```

and

```
table subcategory:

id, name, cat_id
1, cool, 2
2, uncool, 1
3, milf, 2
4, ugly, 1
```

First, can you combine these in a single dropdown box
so the result will be:

```
mymother
 -uncool
 -ugly
hismother
 -cool
 -milf
```

with only the subcategory selectable.

second, can the category/subcategory, when selected, be split again to their 2 original values to be POSTed back again to mysql and inserted into table nmbr.3

```
table parents:
id, phonenmbr, cat_id, subcat_id
```

for a single value it would be simple enough:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM category");
echo "<select name='category'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name']        

"</option>";
```

In order to combine AND split the category_id and the sub_category_id later again, i guess i would need to do two separate sql queries instead of using a JOIN.... but not sure

Comment: **Where is your code which you tried ??**

Answer (score 0):

Probably below code can give you insight of what you need to do :

```
    <form method="get" action="example.php">

            <select id="cd" name="cd">

                <?php

                $mysqlserver="localhost";
                $mysqlusername="test";
                $mysqlpassword="test";
                $link=mysql_connect(localhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                $dbname = 'test';
                mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                $cdquery="SELECT cdTitle, cdArtist, cdReference FROM firsttable";
                $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());

               while ($cdrow=mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
            $cdTitle=$cdrow["cdTitle"];
            $cdArtist=$cdrow["cdArtist"];
            $cdReference=$cdrow["cdReference"];
             echo "<option value=\"$cdReference\">
            $cdTitle $cdArtist
            </option>";
           }

                ?>

            </select>

        </form>
```

Comment: This my good Sir, seems to be exactly the syntax needed.... however... i was looking in returning Both the id for the category and the id for the subcategory to mysql.... but this might be a thinking misstake on my side indeed, i only need the id for the subcategory to be able to identify both..... thank you, problem solved

Comment: Welcome , remember 1 rule of stackoverflow , always ACCEPT ANSWER you think helps you , this helps others in future facing similar problems .